# Dynamically added fields not working with calendar field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to attach a calendar field to a dynamically added html code.
Initially, the code shows 3 input fields (as shown in the "p_scents" div).
When the "Add Another Employer" is clicked, it should generate another 3 inputs( as the ones above).
It is working fine for me to generate the first 2 fields (without the calendar field), but when I add the calendar field, it is not working.

```
<body>
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Employer</a></h2>
    <div id="p_scents">
<p>
    <label>Employer Name</label><input class="dynamic" type="text" name="employern" id="employern" />
    <label>Job Title</label><input class="dynamic" type="text" name="jtitle" id="jtitle" />
    <label>Start Date </label>
<input type="text" name="startd" class="textfield" />
        <script language="JavaScript">
        new tcal ({
        // form name
        'formname': 'form',
        // input name
        'controlname': 'startd'
});
</script>
</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
        if( i <= 10 ) {
            $('<p><label>Employer Name</label><input class="dynamic" type="text"     name="employern' + i +'" id="employern" /><label>Job Title</label><input class="dynamic" type="text" name="jtitle' + i +'" id="jtitle" /><label>Start Date </label>
<input type="text" name="startd' + i +'" class="textfield" />
        <script language="JavaScript">
        new tcal ({'formname': 'form','controlname': 'startd' + i +''});</script><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;}
        else{
            alert('Maximum Reached!');
        }
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there is lot of stuff wrong/not good in your code. I'm trying to give some suggestions how to improve this, but first, what's wrong:

1. **IDs have to be unique.** In your code, you give multiple elements the same ID. Especially the remove link will not work.
2. Strings cannot span multiple lines in JavaScript.
3. Don't add such a bunch of HTML as string. You have a quotation error in this string.
4. Don't add `<script>` tags this way (at least here it is not necessary).

---

**My suggestions:**

Remove the `script` tag from the HTML, you don't need it and remove the IDs of the input elements

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Employer</a></h2>
<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label>Employer Name</label><input class="dynamic" type="text" name="employern" />
        <label>Job Title</label><input class="dynamic" type="text" name="jtitle" />
        <label>Start Date </label>
        <input type="text" name="startd" class="textfield" />
    </p>
</div>
```

You also don't need to use [`live` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for the click event handler on `#addScnt`. Just use [`click` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

```
$('#addScnt').click(...
```

You only need `live` for elements you add dynamically.

Now the most important thing: How you add new fields.

You can do this very easily, by *cloning the existing `p` element*. The only thing you have to remember is to change the name of input fields (add the `i`) and call the `tcal` function:

```
$('#addScnt').click(function() {
    if (i <= 10) {
        $('#p_scents p:first').clone() // clone
            .find('input').attr('name', function(index, value) { // change name
                return value + i;
            }).end()
        .append('<a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a>') // add remove link
        .appendTo(scntDiv);

        // init calender
        new tcal({
            formname: 'form',       
            controlname: 'startd'+i
        });

        i++;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert('Maximum Reached!');
    }
});
```

Reference: [`clone` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), [`attr` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Note that the remove link has a `class`, not an `id`. For this link it is better to use [`delegate` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('#p_scents').delegate('.remScnt', 'click', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).closest('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Also note that I use [`closest` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) here, which only gives the closest `p` element. If you use `parents`, you will remove all ancestor `p` elements and that might result in removing a lot more than you intended.

Last but not least, you also have to make a call to

```
new tcal ({
    // form name
    'formname': 'form',
    // input name
    'controlname': 'startd'
});
```

because we removed the `script` tag.

Here is a working demo of all that: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ygSn9/ (with empty `tcal` function).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback on this. I am still learning javascript and this gave me better understanding of what I was doing. I tried to use the tcal function to insert the calendar to the input field, but it didn't work. I removed certaing attributes to fit the new elements, yet nothing happenned. Can you tell the problem? Here are 2 links: 1- With working calendar (jsfiddle.net/beeko/HL7V7/3) 2- The edited html (jsfiddle.net/beeko/KNqgU/10).